# (iOS Swift) Some features work on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm making an alarm app. There are two things that work on the simulator but not on my device.

1) According to [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/) website, if UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is set to "YES", then the app should always be running even if the device is locked (provided that it's in foreground). I used this information to make sure that NSTimer runs even if device is locked. On the simulator, no matter how much time passes by (even like 10+ hours) the NSTimer always works and the sound always fires (even if I lock the simulator screen). When I connect my iPhone device to the computer and run the app through xcode it works well too. But the problem is that as soon as I disconnect my phone and load the saved app, sometimes the NSTimer works and sometimes it doesn't.

2) Local Notifications: On the simulator the local notifications work well but on the iPhone device the notifications are fired at random times and sometimes they don't even fire. But on the simulator the local notifications fire accurately. I tested in different ways (such as setting local notification to fire 20 seconds after app loads and then exiting the app to be in background mode) but it doesn't fire on the specified time and like I said it sometimes doesn't even fire.

In such case, should I trust simulator or the iPhone device? Could this be a bug or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always trust the device. After all, that's how the end user is going to run your app!

It is well known that you should not trust the Simulator for background behavior. The NSTimer issue is an excellent example. The problem is that the Simulator is your computer, not an iOS device. Timers do not in fact run in the background; the Simulator is misleading you. (The issue where the app behaves differently on the device if being run from Xcode vs. being run independently is a bit more suprising, but in this case I suppose it isn't all *that* surprising; you were very clever to think of testing both ways.)

And of course there are *lots* of iOS features that don't work on the Simulator at all.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem Matt. In the case of NSTimer, it works well on my device so long as it runs through xcode. But when I don't run through xcode then it doesn't...

Comment: "I don't think that's the problem Matt" I don't know what you mean by that. You asked what to trust and I told you the answer. Your test on the device launching from the springboard is the definitive test (and even more definitive if you do a release build); nothing else is. You can believe me or disbelieve me, but that's the answer.

Comment: You certainly answered my question as to what I should trust but I'm still stuck with the first two problems :)

Comment: I repeat: Your only question was "should I trust simulator or the iPhone device?". Everything else was just a description of phenomena. If, for example, you have a question about how to use NSTimer, that is what you should have asked. But you didn't.

Comment: Apps running under Xcode get unlimited background execution time, whether running in the simulator or on a device. You can verify this by logging the `backgroundTimeRemaining` property of your `UIApplication` object from your timer method. You will see that it reaches 0 but your app continues to run. When running independently of Xcode your app will be terminated when this value reaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem for #2. I simply canceled previous notifications before firing new ones.

I'm still facing issues with the first problem.