# Background method stops running on device , only works on simulator swift 4 xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a timer that I want to continue running in the background , on the simulator it works fine. I have the state of the timer printed every “tick” no matter what , and local notification works properly. Then I run it on a real device and the whole program stops... any way to fix this?

Note : I do have background fetch enabled in xcode

Im not sure what else I can do... Please help me!

Comment: Adding some code to the question would be really helpful

Comment: @Zaira Zafar id love to include code but I dont know what is relevent code to this issue... I have a timer that starts when i tap the screen which triggers the onTimerTick(). Inside there the time is printed everytick. THIS METHOD works in background on sim , not on device

Comment: iOS only allows background tasks to run for a specific time. If all you want is to tick a timer, consider saving the time from when the timer is started and then handle the app's foreground and background states to turn on and off the ticker. Use initial time to offset the timer.

Comment: I think this question is similar to yours in term of local notifications and timers. Do check out its answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998852/ios-swift-some-features-work-on-simulator-but-not-on-device?rq=1